# Google Sheets: How set value from two matched columns?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

i'm trying to transform data from a row only list to a row-column structure.

I got data in I:K and want to set the values from K to the corresponding cells in A:H where Date and Time Values from I & J have to match within A:H.

[example sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKcgB.png)

Does anyone know how to do this with Google Sheet system functions?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? Have you looked into the formulas: ( TRANSPOSE, QUERY, FILTER,  ARRAYFORMULA ) ?

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be achieved by using `sumifs` formula, simple and straightforward, here is the formula:

```
=SUMIFS($I$2:$I$13,$G$2:$G$13,$A5,$H$2:$H$13,D$1)
```

And this is how the Gsheet look like, accept if helping you :)

[image]

Comment: Welcome, it is glad to help :)